# Can't call ajax POST request inside FB.api

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For Facebook login I'm using this code

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'birthday,cover,devices,email,first_name,gender,id,last_name,link,location,name,name_format,timezone,verified,website,locale'}, function(response) {


                $.ajax({
                         url: '/login/facebook',
                         type: 'POST',
                         data: { fb: response, window: window.ui},
                         dataType: 'json',
                         success: function (data) {
                             console.log(data); 
                         },

                         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                             notice(xhr);
                             notice(ajaxOptions);
                         }
                });

            });
```

If i'm calling without {fields: '...'} its working but when added fields ajax sending GET request to server instead of post, how to get response with desired fields from FB.API and post it to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem with little change in code instead of `url: '/login/facebook',` I wrote `url: '/login/facebook/',`  just / at the end and problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
FB.api('/me', 'post', {fields: 'birthday,cover,devices,email,first_name,gender,id,last_name,link,location,name,name_format,timezone,verified,website,locale'}, function(response) {
            $.ajax({
                     url: '/login/facebook',
                     type: 'POST',
                     data: { fb: response, window: window.ui},
                     dataType: 'json',
                     success: function (data) {
                         console.log(data); 
                     },

                     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                         notice(xhr);
                         notice(ajaxOptions);
                     }
            });

        });
```

Comment: Yes and its just giving success response {success: true}

Comment: Does The facebook api gives you success: true or your console.log gives that as responds? If it's the last one, then your script handeling login/facebook needs to be check for input/output.

Comment: its giving {success: true}  in console.log

Comment: If that message is comming from your console.log that you need to do manuel post to /login/facebook to check it's reponds. 

Is the url giving back valid json?

Comment: Yes when I'm making post request with ajax from outside of FB.API its giving valid json

Comment: success true I'm getting from FB.API response not from /login/facebook, from FB.API when using your code (with post)